# Iterating Dynamic FileUpload Control Collection in Panel Control using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, panel, dynamic-controls

I'm trying to get the values of dynamically generated FileUpload controls that I add to a Panel:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pFileControls" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
```

I create the controls during a loop through a record set:

```
foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    FileUpload fu = new FileUpload();
    fu.ID = dr["SomeID"].ToString();

    pFileControls.Controls.Add(fu);
}
```

Everything works fine up to the point where I submit the form with this button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnImportFile" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnImportFile_Click" />
```

Which I register like this (Page_Load):

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(btnImportFile);
```

I do this because I'm using a MasterPage/ContentPage setting in my website and mostly everything happens inside an UpdatePanel for AJAXification purposes. Bear in mind that if I explicity specify a FileUpload Control in the HTML view, it works 100%.

When the form is submitted I try to iterate the Panel like this:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in pFileControls.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl.GetType() != typeof(FileUpload))
    {
        continue;
    }

    //Do the saving of the file here
}
```

Except, the Panel seems to only return one control: The Content Place Holder for the page and nothing else. Does anyone have some ideas about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What part of the life cycle are you adding the dynamic controls?

if you are putting them in the page_load it may be too late, try putting the generation of the dynamic controls into the page_init and see if that fixes the problem.

page lifecycle
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

dynamic controls
http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2008/06/26/123391.aspx
Note:

> "Its recommended to load the dynamic
>   controls during the Page_Init instead,
>   because we may want to hook up our
>   events with proper handler at an early
>   stage.  ... Do not assigning
>   properties of a dynamic control
>   (viewstate enabled), during Page_Init,
>   it will not be reflected. "

I would expect that even with the update panel, you will need to be mindful of the page_load limitations with dynamic controls.

let me know if this helps or if I missed the mark!

Let's try a different course of action (I've gotten dynamic file upload to work, but it was a bear and I wish I had simply used this)
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_AsyncFileUpload.ashx

or
http://en.fileuploadajax.subgurim.net/

these may not create a 'loop' of elements, but you can simply keep loading docs on a as-needed basis.

I have specifically used
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_AsyncFileUpload.ashx
to great effect.

There also appear to be some limitations to the update:panel and the file upload, check out these sites.

(this one says it does not work in partial update status but does work in full postback)
http://forums.asp.net/p/1105208/1689084.aspx

do you know if the submit is triggering the full page or just the update:panel? (check out this: http://geekswithblogs.net/mmintoff/archive/2009/04/01/fileupload-within-updatepanel.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much, the second link you gave me cleared it up. I just had to load the controls inside Page_Load instead!

Comment: Ok, maybe I was a bit too hasty. Because I'm recreating the controls everytime on Page_Load, whatever values they contained when they were submitted are lost. Any ideas?

Comment: @mr. Smith, you will need to create the controls on each page load.  place this part into the page_init, they will be recreated on each load but when the viewstate gets loaded your values will be re-inputted (via the viewstate).  by page_load the viewstate is already loaded

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried putting the dynamic generation in Page_Init with no success. When I get to the iteratation part it does find the controls, but they have no "file" (i.e FileUpload.HasFile).

Comment: @Mr. Smith, getting the file loader in ajax can be a trying experience, I would put forth trying out the asp.net ajax toolkit (which I have gotten to work with the file upload) or any of the other free ones out there (I linked to one that looked quite nice).  As for the no file, I would still wonder the lifecycle stage and when you create the control you aren't putting in any properties that could overwrite the postback data?

Comment: I don't set anything other than those two lines of code: FileUpload fu = new FileUpload(); and fu.ID = dr["SomeID"].ToString();. This now happens in Page_Init. I'm still trying a couple of things though, will update soon.

Comment: Ok, this is very strange. When I submit (click the upload button a second time), it does the upload (the controls have files). Finding it hard to understand this behaviour. It should work the first time around?

Comment: @Mr. Smith ahh the joys of dynamic controls.  It sounds like the event is not getting wired up on the initial page load and/or the panel load.  Are there any items that are occurring in a isPostBack clause that may be causing the addition of the event? I am going to add some links above that may (hopefully!) set you on the correct course

Comment: Ok, I figured it out! Basically one of the buttons involved in the process was not registered as a post-back trigger. It's sorted now, thanks!

Comment: @Mr. Smith, could you post your code behind?  (or to be brief specifically your page_load, page_init and your post back handling?)

Comment: @Mr. Smith glad to hear!  happy programming!